# where is dbconsole in grails v3.2.5

Tags: grails

doing some dev mode work on grails 3.2.5 but cant find the /dbconsole applet.

i run my app and go the root url and type /dbconsole, and get a 404.  I tried editing an entry in application.groovy to ensure it was enabled in dev, and explicitly set the urlRoot, to no effect.

has dbconsole been dropped from latest grails builds, or is it there but hidden ?

i tried variations of this in application groovy and in application.yml, to no effect - always get 404 on the browser

```
environments {
    production {
        //grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
        grails.dbconsole.enabled = true
        grails.dbconsole.urlRoot = '/admin/dbconsole'
    }
    development {
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
        grails.dbconsole.enabled = true
        grails.dbconsole.urlRoot = "${appName}/dbc"
    }
    test {
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
    }
}
```

documentation implies it should still work but i am unable to get it to come up

Answer (score 6):

It's http://localhost:8080/h2-console now, not http://localhost:8080/dbconsole . At least in the 4.0.x version of Grails.

Answer (score 2):

ok i think i have it.  I was using Intellij and just imported the project as normal.  however i was running the grails-app/init/application to fire up the app.  I noticed it said it was in production mode - so the fix for that was top copy the run configuration, and call it "application - dev" or something like that.

you then add a line to the VM args "-Dgrails.env=dev" with this.  Now when you run the application by right clicking it shows the new configuration name.

[image: intellij run configuration]

once it was back in dev mode, then you could add the default "/dbconsole" after the root screen and it throws the H2 console.

usual caveats apply on security and protection of this url - but back in business and i can see the tables that Gorm is creating on my behalf.

also if you want to use config.slurper formatting as is still shown in the examples, you need to create an application.groovy in grails-app/conf, and put your entries in there, else i guess you transpose to application.yml format, i find groovy code easier to read somehow.

got there in the end

Comment: PS - this is partly related to inetllij getting its knickers in a twist at some point.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214290/grails-domain-objects-randomly-fail-when-running-app-from-intellij.  so on clean install intellij starts out running the Application in dev mode.  however when it suddenly gets confused /stops working - thats when i noticed that the run-app had swicthed from dev to production as well.  this is 'safe' as it forces it to start in dev on this config, however i'd recommend the gradle clean option (see above ) to remove the random errors

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Grails app is using a different driver, or serving in another address,  take a look at:
[Database Console session](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#databaseConsole)

Comment: "Link only answer" is a category for closure in the review queues. The reason for this is that the goal is for an answer to be useful even if the link in it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

For Latest version 6.0.0 :  [http://localhost:8080/h2-console] is working to open the default db in grails...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).